# How do I delete an entire stream in redis?

Tags: redis, redis-streams

I am new to redis streams, I have googled a lot, but I still cannot figure this question out:
How do I delete an entire stream in redis? I don't need that stream anymore, I want to delete it to release memories and storagies, I wonder if I have to use xdel command to delete all entries in the stream?

Comment: Simply delete the key: `del stream-key`.

Answer (score 2):

As @for_stack has suggested in the comments, you can use the [`DEL` command](https://redis.io/commands/del/) to delete a stream, as you would do with any other key in Redis:

```bash
> DEL mystream
OK
```

The [`XDEL` command](https://redis.io/commands/xdel/) removes the given entry/ies from the stream but not the stream itself:

```bash
> XDEL mystream 1538561700640-0 1538561700655-0
(integer) 2
```

Similarly, the [`XTRIM` command](https://redis.io/commands/xtrim/) can be used to remove older entries from a stream but does not delete the stream itself:

```bash
> XTRIM mystream MINID 649085820
(integer) 42
```